# Integrate: $\int (x^2+a^2)^{-3/2} \cdot dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate: $\int (x^2+a^2)^{-3/2} \cdot dx$

**My Approach:**

$\int (x^2+a^2)^{-3/2} \cdot dx$
$\int (x^2+a^2)^{-3/2} \cdot d(a^2+x^2)\cdot \frac{dx}{d(x^2+a^2)}$

But this doesn't give the right answer. I showed this to my friend and he said $d(x^2+a^2)$ is not possible which makes sense since you can't take a small element of the  form $(x^2+a^2)$. How can I then solve this integration **without using trigonometry**?

Comment: Doing $u$-substitution here, which is what you tried, is *possible* but $d(x^2+a^2)=2xdx$ introduces an $x$ that you'll have to turn into a square root and you won't have gained anything.

Comment: @W.Schlieper could you elaborate, I didn't quite get that

Comment: @W.Schlieper Why would we turn the x into a square root?

Comment: What you're trying to do is rewrite the integral in terms of $u=a^2+x^2$, but the converted integral will introduce a factor of $x^{-1}=(u-a^2)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @W.Schlieper wouldn't we simply solve the integration to get $\frac{-1}{2(2x)} (a^2+x^2)^{-1/2}$

Comment: @OsheenSachdev Oftentimes, you can use this [automatic tool](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) for evaluating integrals. Please try to use this tool before asking a question. (note: This is not spam, and I am not affiliated with the site; posted only to help the OP and future users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your idea we get $du=2xdx$ so :
$$I=\int (x^2+a^2)^{-3/2}  dx=\int\frac{2xdx}{2x(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}=\int \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u^4-a^2u^3}}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u^{3/2}\sqrt{u-a^2}} $$
Let $v=\frac{1}{u-a^2}$, we get $dv=-\frac{1}{(u-a^2)^2}$ :
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(a^2v+1\right)^\frac{3}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}v$$
Let $w=a^2v+1$ then $dw=a^2$ :
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\dfrac{1}{a^2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{w^\frac{3}{2}}\,\mathrm{d}w=\dfrac{1}{a^2\sqrt{w}}$$

And finally :
$$I=\dfrac{1}{a^2\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a^2}}}+C$$

Comment: Oh god...this is so long!

Comment: Could you also help me figure out the error in the answer I wrote in the comment by simply integrating the expression I formulated and then dividing by the derivative $d(x^2+a^2)/dx$

Comment: It is faster you can do the trigonometric substitution $u=\arctan(x/a)$

Comment: Hmm when youmake a subsitution $u=f(x)$ you obtain an expression of $du$ in term of $dx$ and you want to make appear this expression inside your integral, in order to change this expression into $du$ after teh change of variable. You can seefor example in the first line I multiplied both sides of the fraction by $2x$ in order to make appear $du$ and to be able to pursue the change of variable.

Comment: Got it...thank you :)

Comment: This is correct, the substitution is clever, but when in doubt, refer to the trigonometric substitutions. There are rules regarding when to substitute what, simplifying the integral much faster for most questions of these type.

Comment: @GandalftheMathWizard But OP did not want to use a trig substitution :(. But I agree it is much faster :)

Comment: I found a usefull edit :3

Comment: Ight all good, didn't want to down vote a correct solution, cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the correct solution. Note for anything of the form $({x^2+a^2)^{n/2}}$ for n odd, consider using the following trigonometric substituion.

So, let $x=atan(u) \ (or \ x=asinh(u)$ works aswell$)$ $\Rightarrow dx=(a)sec^2(u)du$

Thus we have:

$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx=\int \frac {asec^2u}{(a^2tan^2(u)+a^2)^{3/2}}du=\frac {a}{a^3}\int \frac {sec^2u}{(tan^2(u)+1)^{3/2}}du$$

$$=\frac {1}{a^2}\int \frac {sec^2u}{(tan^2(u)+1)^{3/2}}du=\frac {1}{a^2}\int \frac {sec^2u}{(sec^2(u))^{3/2}}du=\frac {1}{a^2}\int \frac {1}{sec(u)}du=\frac {1}{a^2}\int cos(u)du$$

Finally, we have:

$$=\frac{1}{a^2}sin(u)+c=\frac{1}{a^2}sin(arctan(\frac xa))+c=\frac{x}{a^2 \sqrt{a^2+x^2}}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

We use a trick to get a reduction formula:
$$ \frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{a^2} \frac{x^2+a^2-x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{a^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} - \frac{1}{a^2}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}. $$
The first term is lower-order, the second can be integrated by parts:
$$ \int \frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \, dx = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} + \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}. $$
Oh, but now the new integral on the right here cancels with the integral of the first fraction above! Hence
$$ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{a^2} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} +C, $$
and it's easy to verify this by differentiating.

Comment: How did you integrate the second term?

Comment: Integrate $x/(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}$ (it's an $f'(x)f(x)^a$ form), differentiate the other $x$.